# Cartesian Products with sets in java

Tags: java, set, product, cartesian

I am trying to create a cartesian product method in java that accepts sets as arguments and returns a set pair. The code I have coverts the argumented sets to arrays and then does the cartesian product but i can't add it back to the set pair that i want to return. Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
public static <S, T> Set<Pair<S, T>> cartesianProduct(Set<S> a, Set<T> b) {
    Set<Pair<S, T>> product = new HashSet<Pair<S, T>>();


    String[] arrayA = new String[100];
    String[] arrayB= new String[100];

    a.toArray(arrayA);
    b.toArray(arrayB);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < b.size(); j++){
            product.add(arrayA[i],arrayB[j]);
        }
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `Pair` class from?  Apache Commons?  In any event, I think you'll need to create a `Pair<S,T>` object to use as the argument to `product.add`.  There is no `add` method for sets that takes two arguments.  Also, I assume `arrayA` should be an array of `S`, not `String`... Also, you're not using `toArray` correctly; it will not change the length of the array if `a` is shorter than 100 and won't do anything useful if `a` is larger.  Better is `arrayA = a.toArray(new S[0]);`, similarly for `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks simpler,

```
public static <S, T> Set<Pair<S, T>> cartesianProduct(Set<S> a, Set<T> b) {
    Set<Pair<S, T>> product = new HashSet<Pair<S, T>>();

    for(S s : a) {
        for(T t : b) {
            product.add(new ImmutablePair<S, T>(s,t));
        }
    }

    return product;
}
```

Comment: If this `Pair` is from Apache Commons there's no two-argument constructor, unless I'm looking at an obsolete version of the documentation.  I don't think Java 7 defines a `Pair` class anywhere.  Did they add this to Java 8?

Comment: you're right, just edited, didn't think it was really relevant, he might as well simply implement his own Pair class

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `Pair` from Apache Commons, then I think you want the `add` to be

```
product.add(Pair.of(arrayA[i],arrayB[j]));
```

There's no `add` method for sets that takes two arguments.  You have to create the `Pair` to add to the set.  If that doesn't compile, try

```
product.add(Pair<S,T>.of(arrayA[i],arrayB[j]));
```

Also, I'm assuming you meant `S` and `T` for your arrays, instead of `String`.  There's no reason to preallocate a certain number of elements.  Furthermore, the way you've written it, if there are more than 100 elements in either set, `toArray` will return an all new array with the desired size, but you're not using the function result so that array will be lost.  I'd prefer:

```
S[] arrayA = a.toArray(new S[0]);
T[] arrayB = b.toArray(new T[0]);
```

The zero-length arrays are just "dummies" whose purpose is to get `toArray` to return arrays with the correct element type, instead of `Object[]`.

**EDIT:** Using an enhanced `for` loop is a lot better than using arrays.  See Camilo's answer.